# MySQL for Visual Studio 2015

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2015

For the last 12 hours I've tried to make the MySQL Database appear in Visual Studio 2015. I've downloaded the installer and installed everything. Since that didn't make anything appear in the list of new database connections (Tools > Connect to Database), I started to google. Most of the posts are pre 2013 though. (I also tried 2013 but no luck there either).

I've tried to install EntityFramework, MySql.data, MySql.Data.Entity and so on from the NuGet Package Manager. I've edited the app.config and the packages.config as seen from other tutorials.

But most of what I've read was just "Install and it should work".

Though the MySQL Connector/NET doesn't appear in the list when pressing "About Microsoft Visual Studio". (Should it? I saw someone else have it).
It is 1 am so I'm pretty tired right now.
Does it matter if I have the MySQL installation on a other hard drive? I later reinstalled it on the same hard drive but no difference.

Comment: Which version are you trying to install? 1.2.3 was having issues with VS2015 integration.

Comment: It's 1.2.5, which is the latest available, and the Connector/Net is 6.9.8

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are still searching for a solution to this question given it was asked 6 months ago.

If you are download: [MySQL Installer (v5.7.12 @ 2016-05-18)](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/)

Run the installer and add "MySQL for Visual Studio". Sometimes you have to remove and re add the package for it to work. Add the Connector/Net (v6.9.8 @ 2016-05-18) if it is not installed.

The result is:

[image]

Comment: I am having the same problem.. And simply just installing the mysql installer does not help either, I have tried for days now, trying it over and over again. When everything is downloaded and installed and I try to connect to the database it fails to connect. I just don't understand how it is supposed to be easy.

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the Zip MySql for Windows and extract
2. Open your Solution/Project in Visual Studio and open project properties
3. Select references -> Add -> Browse (Downloaded file directory)
4. Open the top foldder e.g. 14.0v14 and select MySql.data.dll and add
5. Go to Form1.vb or Similar and Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
6. Enjoy!!!